# Multiple Orchestration Functions in a Single Azure Function App

Tags: c#, azure, azure-durable-functions, orchestration

I've created Azure Durable Orchestration Function using a `Fan-out/fan-in` pattern to execute multiple functions concurrently and then performing some aggregation on the results as defined below.

1. A `StarterFunc (TimerTrigger Starter)` function which calls a `OrchestrationOne` function.
2. `OrchestrationOne (OrchestrationTrigger)` is a  orchestrator function that calls a Activity Function i.e. `ActivityOne` to get some array of strings.
3. For each string returned by `ActivityOne` function, the orchestrator calls a another function called `ActivityTwo` in concerrent way using `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)`;

The code looks as below:

```
    [FunctionName("StarterFunc")]
    public static async Task RunScheduled(
        [TimerTrigger("%Starter%")] TimerInfo timerInfo,
        [DurableClient] IDurableClient starter,
        ILogger log)
    {
        var instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync(FuncConstants.OrchestrationDirectToStoreWac, null);
        log.LogInformation($"[{DateTime.UtcNow}] - Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");
    }


    [FunctionName("OrchestrationOne")]
    public async Task Run([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger log)
    {
        // Get all the Strings to be Processed.
        var sList = await context.CallActivityAsync<List<string>>("ActivityOne", null);
        if (sList.Count > 0)
        {
            // Process each String in Parallel
            var parallelTasks = new List<Task<string>>();
            foreach (var s in sList)
            {
                var task = context.CallActivityAsync<string>("ActivityTwo", s);
                parallelTasks.Add(task);
            }

            // Wait for all results to come back
            await Task.WhenAll(parallelTasks);
        }
        else
        {
            //log.LogError
        }
    }
```

I wanted understand, is it possible or better approach to call Multiple Orchestrator functions using Single Starter function? or by Multiple Starter functions inside a single Azure Function App?

For Example :

- Starter One -> Orchestrator One
- Starter Two -> Orchestrator Two

Comment: With the orchestrator that you have described, I don't see any advantage in using multiple orchestrator functions. What benefit are you looking for?

Comment: @juunas I'm planning another orchestrator for another use case which runs independently

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your timer trigger can start as many orchestrators as you want.
Starting an orchestrator consists mainly of two things:

1. Adding a row to the instances table
2. Sending a message to a control queue

Your timer trigger would essentially just do those things several times; there is no issue with that.
The only possible issue would be hitting the execution time limit on the timer trigger (5 minutes by default), but you would have to start *a lot* of orchestrators for that to happen.
Remember that the timer will not wait for the orchestrators to finish, it just adds that row and sends the message.